# Google chart and php arrays

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-visualization

I have the following three `php` arrays. Three of them are key value pairs

`$needles = ["Needle1", "Needle2", "Needle3", "Needle4", "Needle5"];`

`$uph1 = ["Needle1" => 3,  "Needle3" => 5,  "Needle4" => 7];`

`$uph2 = ["Needle1" => 4,  "Needle2" => 2,  "Needle3" => 4];`

`$uph3 = ["Needle1" => 4,  "Needle2" => 5,  "Needle3" => 7,  "Needle4" => 2];`

`$numberOfItems` is the total number of items in the `$needles` array which is 5

I am trying to plot this using google charts as below

The following is loading google charts

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

The following is the `div` that shows chart

`<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>`

The following is populating chart

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
  // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Needle', 'One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    <?php
                
            for($i=0; $i<$numberOfItems; $i++){
                if(array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph1) || array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph2) || array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph3)){
                    if($i != ($numberOfItems-1)){
                        
//                        echo '["'.$needles[$i].'", 2, 4, 6],'; //This is working
                        echo '["'.$needles[$i].'", '.$uph1[$needles[$i]].', '.$uph2[$needles[$i]].', '.$uph3[$needles[$i]].'],'; //This is not working
                    }else{
//                        echo '["'.$needles[$i].'", '.$uph1[$needles[$i]].', '.$uph2[$needles[$i]].', '.$uph3[$needles[$i]].']';
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>

  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Average UPH Per Month',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Avg UPH'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Needle Type'
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      3: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

As you can see my comments in the code above, when I try to `echo` the array (`$uph1, $uph2, $uph3`) values using the key (`$needles[$i]`), it is not working. I having `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` error in my console. I used some static values instead of using the above mentioned arrays, it is working fine.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

** Edit 1 **

I solved it adding the following `if` condition before the `if($i != ($numberOfItems-1)){ }`

```
if(array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph1)){
    $uph1Avg = $uph1[$needles[$i]];
}else{
    $uph1Avg = 0;
}

if(array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph2)){
    $uph2Avg = $uph2[$needles[$i]];
}else{
    $uph2Avg = 0;
}

if(array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph3)){
    $uph3Avg = $uph3[$needles[$i]];
}else{
    $uph3Avg = 0;
}
```

Issue was due to some of the keys don't exist in the key value arrays `$uphx`. Because the main `if` condition is checking if key exist or not in any one of the `$uphx` array. So if any one key exist, it will go into `if` block. But please remember that some of the keys may not present in some of the `$uphx` arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push your array value inside *javascript* array and then pass this to your google chart . So, use below code :

```
<script>
var arrays = [['Needle', 'One', 'Two', 'Three']] //your intial column..
var dummy = [] //declare this
 <?php
      for($i=0; $i<count($needles); $i++){ ?>
        dummy.push('<?php echo $needles[$i]; ?>',<?php echo (array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph1)) ? $uph1[$needles[$i]] : 0 ; ?>,<?php echo (array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph2)) ? $uph2[$needles[$i]] : 0 ; ?>,<?php echo (array_key_exists($needles[$i],$uph3)) ? $uph3[$needles[$i]] : 0 ; ?>)  
        arrays.push(dummy)//push value inside main array
        dummy =[] //clear all value
 <?php }
  ?>
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    arrays); //pass it here

  var options = {
    title: 'Average UPH Per Month',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Avg UPH'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Needle Type'
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      3: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

***Output*** :

[image]

Comment: Thank you Swati. I solved it using php way itself. Issue was due sometimes there is `array_key_exists` only for certain `$uphx`. But since there is at least one exist, it will go into the `if` condition. However there is no `value` for other `$uphx` keys. That is why error. I did one more check inside the main `if` condition and it works. Anyway thanks for your way of solving it too

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to pass your php table to javascript and do the processing in javascript before using it to create yout charts

```
var needles = <?php echo json_encode($needles); ?>
```